# Build Notification Center in javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, notifications

I'm building a small app in js, using the mvc pattern. I want to separate totally the view and the control so I though a notification center control would be a good solution. UI objects fire a notification with data attached in which is recorded the id, the event and other data.

You think is a good solution?

Which could be wise ways to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to write something like `EventEmitter` in nodejs.

https://github.com/tmpvar/node-eventemitter

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think it's a good idea to implement the Observer pattern (Notification Center) in user interfaces; specifically because doing so allows you to easily add features and functionality later in the life of the application. I think it would be wise to implement the [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for your Notification Center. You should consider reading Apple's implementation of their Cocoa Framework's Notification Center for inspiration and examples on usage.